# Angular 11 routes not working to get language parameter

Tags: angular, routes

I would like to fetch the language as get parameter from current active url:

I have tried:-

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path : '/:lang',  component: myComponent
  }
 ];

 In Component, in ngOnInit method:

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( (params : Params) => {
    console.log(params['lang'])
  });

 Am calling url, localhost:4200/en

 Output in console:

 {}
```

Comment: Try `path: /':lang', pathMatch: 'full',  component: myComponent`. Also maybe `path: ':lang'`

Comment: @Benny, I have tried both suggestions but not working, Thanks for the help!

Comment: See my implementation here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-params

Comment: @Benny got undefined in console!

Comment: Can you upload a reproducible app to Stackblitz?

Comment: i have written my code in app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228786/discussion-between-benny-and-youv).